# Enhanced for-loop stopped with NullPointerException

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

My enhanced for loop doesn't seem to be iterating correctly.  The purpose is to use the search class to go through an ArrayList of type Contact and find a specific name but for some reason it only goes through the first contact and stops with an error after that displaying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at client.AddressBook.search(AddressBook.java:17)
    at Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

**My Main class is below:**

```
import client.AddressBook;
import client.Contact;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AddressBook ab = new AddressBook();

        Contact c1 = new Contact("jeffm@engr.uconn.edu");
        ab.add(c1);

        Contact c2 = new Contact("jeffm@engr.uconn.edu", "Jeff Meunier", "jeff");
        ab.add(c2);

        Contact c3 = new Contact("billgates@engr.uconn.edu", "Bill Gates", "bill");
        ab.add(c3);

        System.out.println(ab.search("jeff"));
    }

}
```

**The AddressBook and Contact class are also listed below:**

```
package client;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AddressBook {

    ArrayList<Contact> al = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    public void add(Contact contactAdd) {

        al.add(contactAdd);
    }

    public Contact search(String searchName) {

        for(Contact obj: al) {

            if(obj.getNickName().equals(searchName)) {
                return obj;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String remove(String nickname) {

        search(nickname);
        al.remove(nickname);

        return nickname;
    }

    public void show() {

        int x = 1;
        for(Contact obj: al) {

            System.out.println(x + ". " + obj.toString());
            x++;
        }
    }
}



package client;

public class Contact {

    public String _emailAddress = null;
    public String _fullName = null;
    public String _nickName = null;

    public Contact(String emailaddress, String fullname, String nickname) {

        _emailAddress = emailaddress;
        _fullName = fullname;
        _nickName = nickname;
    }

    public Contact(String emailaddress) {

        _emailAddress = emailaddress;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        if(_fullName == null & _nickName == null) {

            //System.out.println("<" + _emailAddress + ">");
            return _emailAddress;
        }
        else {
            //System.out.println(_fullName + " (" + _nickName + ") " + "<" + _emailAddress + ">");
            return _fullName + " (" +  _nickName + ") " + "<" + _emailAddress + ">";
        }
    }

    public String getNickName() {

        return _nickName;
    }
}
```

If anyone can give any pointers it would be greatly appreciated.  Ultimately right now I am only testing to see whether the search class can search for a specified nickname and then print out the returned value of that.  Obviously it should be returning the second Contact (or at least that is the intention).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happen in this validation :

```
 if(obj.getNickName().equals(searchName)) {
     return obj;
 }
```

It seems like `obj.getNickName()` may sometime be null.

Change the order of your validation :

```
public Contact search(String searchName) {

    for(Contact obj: al) {
        //I assume that searchName will never be null
        if(searchName.equals(obj.getNickName()) {
            return obj;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help that was the issue and returns the proper contact now that I can assume the search will not eer be null.

Answer (score 1):

Your first item you add does not include a nickname. in your search you get the nickname and call equals() on a null reference.

Comment: Nice finding I am just going to post it. But you post it earlier. But I think the best solution is to use Jean-François Savard answer in this case.